# How to unit-test an AngularJS service that uses localStorage internally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, local-storage

How do I unit-test a factory that uses `$window.localStorage` internally using Jasmine and ngMock?

Here's something similar to what I have:

```
myApp.factory('myData',function ($window) {
    return { 
        message: $window.localStorage['stuff'] 
    }
});
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works with Jasmine 2.4:

```
angular.module('MyModule', []).factory('myData',function ($window) {
    return { 
        message: function(){
          return $window.localStorage['stuff'] ;
        }
    }
});

describe("TestName", function() {
  beforeEach(module('MyModule'));
  var myData, store;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_myData_) {
    myData = _myData_;
    store = {};
    var localStorage = window.localStorage;
    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake(function (key) {
      return store[key];
    });
    spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem').and.callFake(function (key, value) {
      return store[key] = value + '';
    });
    spyOn(localStorage, 'clear').and.callFake(function () {
      store = {};
    });
  }));

  it("feature desc", function() {
    localStorage['stuff'] = 'hello';
    expect(myData.message()).toEqual('hello');
  });
});
```

Note use of the _myData_ underscore trick ([see docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject#resolving-references-underscore-wrapping-)).

Comment: Great. This worked. Don't know why but I was trying to mock the factory as well.

Answer (score 3):

Small clarification: in case localStorage doesn't contain a key this mock return `undefined`, but real one returns `null`

> The getItem(key) method must return the current value associated with
>   the given key. If the given key does not exist in the list associated
>   with the object then this method must return null.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

```
  spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake(function (key) {
    return store[key] !== undefined ? store[key] : null;
  });
```

Note: in the previous example method `removeItem` was not mocked

```
  spyOn(localStorage, 'removeItem').and.callFake(function (key, value) {
    delete store[key];
  });
```

P.S. I've found another way to write tests with local storage without mock it, probably it makes sense, working with primitives and localStorage could be tricky.

```
afterEach(() => {
  localStorage.removeItem(testTokenKey);
});
```

Comment: Local storage persists between tests.  Deleting local storage keys is a great way to prevent side effects from one test to another.